# Accessing checked checkbox values in play2.0 framework for java

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, checkbox

I am generating multiple checkbox using below code:

```
@if(ctagList.isEmpty()){
<b>no tags</b>
} else {
@repeat(inputForm("ctags"), min=1 ){ctags =>
@for(getIn <- ctagList) {
@checkbox(ctags, '_label-> getIn.get(0))
} } }
```

Accessing checked values in `List<String>` as below:

```
getCheckedCTags checkedCTags=filledCtagsForm.get();
List<String> iHaveTags=getCheckedCTags.getMeCTagsList(checkedCTags);
```

And rendering it as: `return ok(index.render(iHaveTags));` On rendered page I have code like `@create.get(0)` to see the checked checkbox values. After running code, and selecting checkbox options I could just see **True** instead of getting the list of all checked checkbox values.

I was been referring http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers and https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/6mdGjuaYGaI

Guys could you please tell me what wrong I am doing. Thanks

Comment: guys any thought on this still I am searching for it.